# PHP: Checking if a reflection class has a constructor?

Tags: php

I wrote a dependency provider (basically IOC container) for my application. I added the feature of autowiring, although it hits a snag when the class it is trying to autowire doesn't have a constructor.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getParameters() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\app\Providers\DependencyProvider.php:68
```

I am fairly certain it is trying to resolve constructor arguments in the `resolveArguments` method, on a class that doesn't have a constructor, and this is why the issue is happening.

So, `resolveArguments` should only be called if the class needs their arguments resolved (autowired), and that is usually only when it has a constructor.

The error message above, is happening because `getConstructor` is returning null. I am asking what is the best practice to check if a reflection class has a constructor that needs autowiring?

Full class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class DependencyProvider {
    private static $objects = [];

    /**
     * Register an instantiated object to the container.
     *
     * @param object $object
     */
    public static function register(object $object) : void {
        self::$objects[get_class($object)] = $object;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch a cached object from the container.
     *
     * @param string $objectName
     * @return object
     */
    public static function fetch(string $objectName) : object {
        if (array_key_exists($objectName, self::$objects)) {
            return self::$objects[$objectName];
        }

        $object = self::make($objectName);

        self::$objects[$objectName] = $object;

        return $object;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an object from its name and auto-wires constructor arguments.
     *
     * @param string $objectName
     * @return object
     * @throws \ReflectionException
     */
    private static function make(string $objectName) : object {
        $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($objectName);

        if (!$reflection->isInstantiable()) {
            throw new RuntimeException($reflection->getName() . ' can\'t be instantiated.');
        }

        $arguments = self::resolveArguments($reflection);

        if (count($arguments) < 1) {
            return $reflection->newInstance();
        }
        else {
            return $reflection->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an array of arguments from a reflection class.
     * Uses default value if there is one, auto-wires the object if not.
     *
     * @param $reflection
     * @return array
     */
    private static function resolveArguments($reflection) : array {
        $constructor = $reflection->getConstructor();
        $parameters = $constructor->getParameters();

        if (!$parameters) {
            return $reflection->newInstance();
        }

        $arguments = [];

        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
            if ($parameter->isDefaultValueAvailable()) {
                $arguments[] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
                continue;
            }

            if ($parameter->getClass() == null) {
                exit($parameter->name . ' on ' . $reflection->getName() . ' needs a default value');
            }

            $arguments[] = self::fetch($parameter->getClass()->getName());
        }

        return $arguments;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than $reflection->getConstructor() !== null

Answer (score 1):

Edit (misread the question):

Just check that the constructor actually exists before calling that method:

```
if (! is_null($reflection->getConstructor())) { ... }
```